# Terminal command to show a specific line extract from the output, along with the full output

Tags: linux, mac-osx, command-line-interface, terminal

I have a build command that outputs a lot of content, and within it, there's a link that I need to copy & paste.

So I'd like to be able to do some terminal acrobatics so that this command does the normal full output, but in the end, but that line with the link is extracted and concatenated to the bottom of the output, so I can easily locate it.

I cannot modify this command itself.

Example:

```
$ buildcommand
line1
line2
this is the link: http://link
linex
liney
```

Desired outcome:

```
$ buildcommand | magic
line1
line2
this is the link: http://link
linex
liney
this is the link: http://link
```